# Posting form data failing

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

There's a form created with:

```
<form action="posting.php" method="post" name="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)">
```

When I post the form's data to posting.php, it sends me back to the page the form is on. I tried entering the form manually without fields filled and it includes an error message on the page when something is missing, which was not in the HTML of the page when I submit it (I print it to the shell to see where it got).

I've tried using mechanize with no success.

The forms according to mechanize:

```
<TextControl(subject=)>
<TextControl(sub_title=)>
<HiddenControl(<None>=black) (readonly)>
<SelectControl(addbbcode18=[*#, darkred, red, orange, brown, yellow, green, olive, cyan, blue, darkblue, indigo, violet, white, black])>
<HiddenControl(<None>=12) (readonly)>
<SelectControl(addbbcode20=[7, 9, *12, 18, 24])>
<HiddenControl(<None>=:)) (readonly)>
<TextareaControl(message=)>
<HiddenControl(=) (readonly)>
<HiddenControl(mode=newtopic) (readonly)>
<HiddenControl(f=1521) (readonly)>
<HiddenControl(last_post=0) (readonly)>
<CheckboxControl(disable_bbcode=[on])>
<CheckboxControl(disable_smilies=[on])>
<CheckboxControl(notify=[*on])>>
```

My posting code (post_url is "domainname.posting.php"):

```
def post_data(url, values={}): #either read a page or post to a page
    if values != {}: #if values were provided, post request
        data = urllib.urlencode(values) #encode the valyes
        req = urllib2.Request(url, data=data) #make the request
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(req) #get the response
        return resp.read() #return the read page
    else: #no values, normal read request
        req = urllib2.Request(url) #request the url
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(req) #get the reponse 
        return resp.read() #return the read page

print post_data(post_url, {"subject":"Test Post","sub_title":"","message":"Test","<None>":"black", "addbbcode18":"black","<None>":12,"addbbcode20":"12","<None>":":","last_post":"0","disable_bbcode":"on","disable_smilies":"on","notify":"on",None:None,"mode":"newtopic","f":"1521"})
```

Does the form data order need to match the form's order (as shown by mechanize)? Maybe I'm providing invalid value types for the form ("disable_bbcode":"on" for example, should it be "disable_bbcode":"[*on]"?). It might be the onsubmit in the form declaration, and if that is the issue, how do I submit it too?

Notes:

- In the html that gets printed out, the values for "subject", and "message" are blank, so I'm guessing the values never get posted.
- I suspect "mode" and "f" are GET methods, but when I try posting to "posting.php?mode=newtopic&f=1521" (with "mode" and "f" removed from the posted values), I get the same results.

Comment: I might be missing something, but your form action is `posting.php` but your posting code is python. What happens when you change your file extension to `posting.py`?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear, I'm posting to a form on a website using urllib and urllib2.